# Array Name being described as a String

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I Have multiple arrays and I want to choose one to be my main array. I want the main Array to be described as a String. How can I name the new array by using my StationID String and my DirectionID String?

```
    let Farbhof1 = ["hi","some","Strings"]

    var StationID = "Farbhof"
    var DirectionID = "1"

DestViewController.TableViewArray = "\(StationID)\(DirectionID)"
```

Comment: Programming languages don't work that way. You will to put the arrays into a dictionary first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in Swift. Variable names need to be known at compile time, they cannot be calculated at runtime.